# How to differentiate between inventory in different sites?

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm using the `ListInventorySupply` action to get all my inventory

https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01?AWSAccessKeyId ....

Now the response includes ALL my inventory for all European sites. How can I know which items are in .uk and which in .de etc?

Comment: I realise this question is ancient but looking for a way to do this myself. I'm thinking of first issuing one Reports API call to get a local copy of our inventory with FNSKUs and inventory locations.
From there if you are using the simple `ListInventorySupply` call you should be able to determine where the item is matching up the FNSKU with your local database.

Comment: hi @MrOffice, thats exactly what i ended up doing. add the site gTLD to the sku...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with FBA, but it is my understanding that the `FullfillmentInventory` API call does not give you fulfillment center information and neither lets you specify a specific fulfillment center as query parameter.

There is another set of API calls from the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__FBAReports) that most probably do what you want. I suggest you look specifically at the `_GET_AFN_INVENTORY_DATA_BY_COUNTRY_` report type.

Comment: thanks. i wasn't aware of this API. i will check it out. but since it might take some time, ill meanwhile mark this as answer. thanks!!